# std::unordered_map - how to "track" max/min key at any time

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, unordered-map, boost-multi-index

I have `std::unordered_map<int, int>`.
I do not want to use other structures like tree or anything else cause latency requirements.
But at any time I need to know current max key and min key.
How can I do that? Distribution is NOT uniform, instead max and min are frequently removed and inserted. So I need something smarter than "just scan entire map for a new max/min when current max/min is removed".

I do not want to use any other structures. I want to use `std::unordered_map`!

**upd** according to the answer created such structure:

```
struct OrderBookItem {
    int64_t price;
    int32_t lots;
};

typedef multi_index_container
    <OrderBookItem, indexed_by<

    hashed_unique<
    BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(OrderBookItem,int64_t,price)
    >,

    ordered_unique<
    BOOST_MULTI_INDEX_MEMBER(OrderBookItem,int64_t,price),
    std::greater<int64_t>
    >

    >> OrderBookContainer;
```

Comment: I don't think you can track the min and the max after deletions for an unordered container. To do that you inherently require keeping an ordering on the elements so you know which one comes before the min/max you just removed.

Comment: As Mehrdad says, you ask the impossible.  There are some compromises you could flirt with if memory usage is a huge issue - such as keeping fixed-size top-N and bottom-N buffers as you insert and erase and only recreating them when you've lost track of the min or max - depending on access patterns that might be after 10N or more operations.  For average overheads though, a parallel balanced binary tree (i.e. `std::map`) is a good way to go.  Note that your unordered_map lookup will still be just as fast... it's just your insert and erase will slow down to binary tree performance levels.

Comment: why you want `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: because `std::unordered_map` is fast

Comment: @javapowered But it's fast precisely because it doesn't keep an ordering of the elements...

Comment: You cannot eat your cake and have it too.

Comment: If you need an order, you need an order! The only reason to use an unordered_map in this case is if you are either only adding data, or are willing to suffer the hit of searching the map for the new highest/lowest if you removed one of them.

Comment: -1, but mom I want to use X is not a proper Q

Comment: How many elements are we talking about? Have you compared speed using a `std::map` or a `boost::container::flat_map` (http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx)? How frequent are inserts compared to removals? If inserts are much more frequent than inserts then increasing the min/max on insert, but invalidating it on removal could perhaps be an option.

Comment: possible duplicate of [unordered\_map with "max and min key" tracking?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21259269/unordered-map-with-max-and-min-key-tracking)

Comment: @Sneftel yes I created new question because this question was about c++ while previous question was about algorithm in general. I likely better modify previous question somehow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Your exact requirements cannot be met**: `std::unordered_map` is fast (i.e. `O(1)` insertion/erasure/lookup) because it doesn't order its elements. This means that finding the minimum/maximum takes `O(N)`.

The price of ordering paid by `std::map` that insertion/erasure/lookup (including finding the minimum/maximum) all become `O(log N)`.

If you don't mind using Boost, you could take a look at the [**Boost.MultiIndex**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) library. This allows you to access your data by multiple interfaces simultaneously. It is an extremely versatile and high-performance library that can also be used for MRU cache data structures (which also combine fast access and tracking of an ordering).

Your primary `std::unordered_map` interface is provided by the `hashed_unique` index, where you use an `identity` function object (provided by Boost.MultiIndex). Your secondary interface would mimic a `std::set`. This allows finding the minimum/maximum value in `O(1)` time as `*begin()` and `*rbegin()`.

You can do that by adding a `ordered_unique` index with a user-defined `MyOrder` function object to compute whatever criterion you like to use to order them. Small code example (omitting the `boost::` namespace everywhere)

```
using MyContainer = multi_index_container<
    Item,
    indexed_by<
        hashed_unique<identity<Item>>, // O(1) erasure/lookup, O(log N) insertion
        ordered_unique<MyOrder<Item>>  // track minimum/maximum in O(log N)
    >
>;
```

Behind the scenes, Boost.MultiIndex implements this roughly as a `std::set<Value>` with a `std::unordered_map<Key, set<Value>::iterator>`. This means both lookups and erasures are `O(1)`. The erasure can be `O(1)` because the `unordered_map::erase(value)` returns an iterator into the `set` and `std::set<Value>::erase(iterator)` is `O(1)`.

However, insertions remain `O(log N)`, because you cannot avoid finding the rank of a newly inserted value within an ordered sequence in less time.

This improvement compared to `std::map` for lookup/erasure costs **only a few pointers per element space overhead**.

Comment: i think A is wrong, since he will still have logarithmic complexity because of the min max... so it is same if not worse than using just a map, because he says insertions are frequent(if it was mostly lookups it would be better)

Comment: so you are saying maintaining ordered index when inserting is O(1) ?

Comment: I dont see it in documents, basically I dont understand how *new* iterator from unordered map helps you inserting in a *different* map. IDK if that is even legal behavior, to give one maps iterator as hint for another map...

Comment: @NoSenseEtAl thanks for pointing out my mistake! I corrected my answer to reflect the `O(log N)` insertion. Note that erasure is still `O(1)` due to the iterator indirection.

Comment: why this is better than just "std::map"?

Comment: @javapowered because `std::map` has `O(log N)` lookup and erasure for all elements. The Boost.MultiIndex has `O(1)` lookup and erasure for all elements.

Comment: sorry for simple question. assuming that i need `unordered_map<int, int>` what is `Item`?

Comment: @javapowered `Item` would be the `value_type` of `unordered_map`, i.e. `std::pair<int, int>`

Comment: how to tell that hashed_unique should use first `int` of pair for hashing?

Comment: @javapowered thatis done using [key extraction](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0b1/libs/multi_index/doc/reference/key_extraction.html). Using Boost.MultiIndex requires a bit of a learning curve, but the docs are excellent.

Comment: thanks, marking your answer as correct but likely I will spent couple days learning multiindex.

Comment: @javapowered or just test with map and see how much it is slower from unordered_map before that

Comment: what is slower than what?

Comment: posted my structure to the question. I think i should not use "identity" function instead i would prefer to hash by price

Comment: probably you can help me review my implementation too! thank in advance :) http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/39870/boost-multi-index-based-orderbook

Answer (score 0):

You can write a wrapper. With that, you get every insertion/deletion and can retain min / max values.

```
#pragma once

#include <unordered_map>

using std::unordered_map;

class my_unordered_map
{
public:
    void insert(int key, int value)
    {
        _map[key] = value;
        if (_max < value)
            _max = value;
        if (_min> value)
            _min = value;
    }
    int get(int key)
    {
        auto it = _map.find(key);
        if (it != _map.end())
            return it->second;
        return 0; // or some error handling here.
    }
    int getMin()
    {
        return _min;
    }
    int getMax()
    {
        return _max;
    }
    // more functionality here.
private:
    unordered_map<int, int> _map;
    int _min = 0;
    int _max = 0;
};
```

Comment: @poljpocket A wrapper was my initial thought too, but what happens when you remove the max value from the map? How do you find the second-highest value?

Comment: This example code conveniently avoids the one operation that is problematic: deletion.

Comment: I know, I'll try to figure out a solution tonight.

Comment: @poljpocket is it still day out there..? :P